# Understanding Estimation of Liner Co-efficients

Tags: linear-regression

As I was going through some documentation on how to estimate the linear co-efficients (intercept and weights) here in this page (https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linear_regression.html)

I could not understand the following statement:

> There are two parameters (coefficients) in our cost function we can
>   control: weight  and bias . Since we need to consider the impact
>   each one has on the final prediction, we use partial derivatives. To
>   find the partial derivatives, we use the Chain rule. We need the chain
>   rule because (−(+))2 is really 2 nested functions: the inner
>   function −(+) and the outer function 2.

What I do not understand is which is the outer function that they define here as x2?

Comment: The considered function is $x^2$

Comment: The outer function is $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},x\mapsto x^2$, the square-function

Comment: This is what I do not understand! Is it that they treat the square function as a separate function? I need more elaborate explanation please!

Comment: Yes, the inner function is $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R},(x,y)\mapsto y-(mx+b) $ and so $(f\circ g)(x,y)=f(g(x,y))=(y-(mx+b))^2$, now use the chain rule to get $\frac{\partial f\circ g}{\partial x}=2(y-(mx+b))(-m)$ and $\frac{\partial f\circ g}{\partial y}=2(y-(mx+b))$

Comment: From where are you getting the -m in the chain rule where you partially derivate over x?

Comment: $\frac{\partial (y-(mx+b))}{\partial x}=-m$.

Comment: Got that! Thanks!